# Keeping typed in form data in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form where i would like the data to be still present in the form fields if there is a form validation error. By default when i try to submit data in the form django clears all the fields. What is the best approach for doing this using django 1.6 ?

I thought i would just fetch data like so: request.POST['field'], send it to the template and then let the template run a conditional if statement by im getting an error from django telling me that the values isnt found in the multidict but it is found when i fill out the form field so that doesnt seem to work. I also tried to check if the value was present directly in the view but i ended up with a ridicoulus amount of if statements to be able to do this which is just an ugly hack.

Can someone suggest a good working solution on this ? Ive seem threads on SO on kind of the same problem but people just wrote that it should be the default to keep data but that doesnt seem to be the case for django 1.6.

Comment: Are you using class based or function based views?

Comment: The  documentation on [using a form in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) shows exactly what to do, and this has not changed in 1.6.

Comment: at this time im still using function based views. ive read the docs daniel and i cant see how it solves my particular problem..it says how to handle a form, not how to keep data already typed in if the form doesnt validate.. ive done that, im not binding a form if there isnt post data and binding it if there is, and running form.is_valid , but if form.is_valid fails then all fields are cleared.. maybe im missing something but ive read that more than once

Answer (score -1):

I imagined your form class `MyForm()`. If the form is not valid send `form = MyForm(request.POST)` to template.

**some view:**

```
def myview(request):

   if request.method=='POST':
      form = MyForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         form.save()
         return render(request, 'success.html')
   else:
      form = MyForm()
   return render(request, 'form.html',{'form':form})

<form action="." method="POST">
{{form}}
</form>
```

Comment: You're instantiating the form twice here unnecessarily, and not redirecting away on success.

Comment: that basically what im doing but it clears the form field if the form doesnt validate

Comment: i now see that you were using {{ form }}, well i dont like to do that because i like to style the fields and have complete control, maybe thats why it doesnt work..